# What's wrong with "Las hijas son inteligentes"

Tags: adjetivos

I am new to Spanish, and I am looking at this sentence

**Las hijas son inteligentes**

it seems to be wrong based on feedback of a exam I am taking, but I am not sure why. I suspect that "inteligentes" is masculine, then what is its feminine form, please?

Comment: As is now, the sentence is correct. What feedback did you get? What were you told about it that makes you think it has something wrong? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Is there a feminine form of inteligente?

Comment: ‘Inteligente’ is a characteristic, so ‘ser inteligente’ is correct. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/est%C3%A1s-eres-inteligente.335655/

Comment: Since it seems gramatically correct, is it possible that it was only wrong in context? For instance, could the context have required that it be "las niñas son inteligentes" ("girls are intelligent" or "the girls are intelligent") instead? Or "los hijos son inteligentes," because it was referring to a group of sons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There's nothing wrong with the use of the adjective** `inteligentes` in your sentence. In Spanish, nouns and adjectives finishing with `nte` doesn't have masculine/feminine variation, for example:

- **El/la** `agente`.
- **El** chico es `pedante` / **La** chica es `pedante`.
- **El** `estudiante` no es muy `inteligente` / **La** `estudiante` no es muy `inteligente`.
- **Las** galletas quedaron `crujientes` / **El** pan quedó `crujiente`.

You can actually find this rule in the [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg):

> También los sustantivos terminados en -ante o -ente, procedentes en gran parte de participios de presente latinos, y que funcionan en su gran mayoría como comunes, e**n consonancia con la forma única de los adjetivos con estas mismas terminaciones** (complaciente, inteligente, pedante, etc.)

---

There are few "exceptions" that may turn-up in the context of gender-inclusive language:

- Presid**ente** (m) / Presid**enta** (f)
- Dirig**ente** (m) / Dirig**enta** (f)

Comment: 'Presidenta' is OK for a female president, but 'dirigenta' sounds terrible to me. The DRAE does not accept it either.

Comment: @Spuny I'm well aware of the fact that the RAE doesn't recognize the word dirigenta (and not so long ago, it didn't recognize presidenta either). But we can't deny it's common use in some contexts: just make a Google News search of the word dirigenta.

Comment: How does _presidenta_ turn up in the context of gender-inclusive language? It rather seems to be the exact opposite to me. Given that words in _-ente_ are inherently gender-ambiguous, getting rid of _presidenta_ (except perhaps in the sense ‘president’s wife’) and just using _presidente_ everywhere would surely be much more gender-inclusive…

Answer (score 2):

> Las hijas son inteligentes

Problemas :

¿ De quién son las hijas ?

e.g. “Las hijas de Pedro son inteligentes” or “Mis hijas son inteligentes”

El uso de inteligentes no tiene nada de malo.